# Grouping with latest time from SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-by, max

Im trying to make a messaging system, but I'm stuck at a problem for too long now.
When I excute my query, it returns the total amount of rows that have time, instead of the time of the latest row.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Ths is my query:

```
SELECT i.`from` , SUM( i.`read` ) , COUNT( i.id ) , i.`time` , m.username
FROM  `messages` i
JOIN  `members` m ON i.`from` = m.`id` 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY i.`from` 
ORDER BY i.`time`
```

I have tried

```
MAX(i.`time`)
```

But that doesn't work.

Not sure what went wrong, but it works now.
Here is the new query if anyone wonders how and what.

```
SELECT i.`to`, m.`username`, max(i.`time`)
FROM `messages` i
JOIN `members` m ON i.`to` = m.`id`
WHERE i.`from` = ?
GROUP BY i.`from`
ORDER BY i.`time`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the latest time:

```
SELECT i.`time`
FROM  `messages` i
JOIN  `members` m ON i.`from` = m.`id` 
ORDER BY i.`time` DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Or `top 1` or whatever flavor your db supports.

If you want it per `from`, then this:

```
SELECT i.`from`, max(i.`time`)
FROM  `messages` i
JOIN  `members` m ON i.`from` = m.`id` 
GROUP BY i.`from`
ORDER BY 2
```

But from your question I assume you already tried this?

Comment: I need multiple results. So the query returns multiple rows.

Comment: But multiple results of what? Of `max(time)` per `from`?

Comment: Nope I only need 1 time, but I got it working just before I was your post. Thankyou anyway ^^